# Can we build a multiplayer quiz app with on Android with Ktor

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, ktor

I'm searching an alternative to Firebase. I searched for tools (like google play games but I don't like the leaderboard, or Playfab seems to be outdated and in Java...) to make my quiz app multiplayable and have a leaderboard where I can example get the 10 000th player rank without having to load 9 999 scores to help the user find himself on the leaderboard (Firebase problem). I so think about Ktor to implement my own server and I wonder if it can achieve all of that things mentioned above. I target Android Platform and I want to develop in Kotlin.

Thank you !

Comment: Yes, you can ....

Comment: Why "..."? Is my question stupid? Sorry about that because I'm beginner Android developper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Ktor, Ktor would run on some web server you'd need to deploy. Yu can set up the routing of requests in any way you want with Ktor, so your example of the 10000th ranked player would be straight forward.

Your android app would be a client app of the web server and make http requests to it. Ktor has lots of good tutorials. This [one](https://ktor.io/docs/getting-started-ktor-client.html) seems relevant

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ktor is a name for both a server framework and an API client. You can write your server using Ktor Server and use Ktor Client on Android.

Comment: Could you provide a link or tutorial with your answer?